# Loading a Xaml Resource in a WinUI Component

Tags: windows, c++-winrt, winui-3

I am running an unpackaged app and manually loading objects across a Proxy-Stub Server using base.h. I have a Window.Xaml with a Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Frame as the root element, in a WinUI component. I have tried both calling to get the IActivationFactory to the Xaml resource and creating it using:

```
auto oMyWindow = oObj.ActivateInstance<Window>();
```

or getting a runtime class to `make<MyWindow>()` the resource, but Initialize() fails both ways with:

```
WinRT originate error - 0x80004005 : 'Cannot locate resource from 'ms-appx:///MyWindow.xaml'.'.
```

Is there something I am unaware of that can be done to fix this so I can proceed? My alternative is using separate .exe processes to encapsulate, but this requires a lot of IPC work. It's not that I won't have to use other IPC options, it's just that I'd like to keep my late bound modules, tightly bound. And no, I have no intention of manually loading an entire interface with multiple pages.

Comment: The answer to this question is, it is not at all possible at this time. It would require Xaml Island type functionality, and this functionality will not be present until sometime in 2023. Using the UWP Xaml Island framework is not an option. The only option is to build pages dynamically through run time code, rewire the entire WinUI system yourself, or simply encapsulate in called .exe processes; where calling executables is the only realistic option for a complex UI. This just enforces the use of non-COM/WinRT IPC, which sucks because I like interfaces.

Answer (score -1):

Your application seems to be unable to find the file you're referencing. Make sure the application has the correct path. Using an absolute path instead of a relative path should work.

Comment: make<>() is an API call you make that is pathless; it is made based on hard types. If you make the same call in an executable the function call works fine. In both of my cases make<>() is called. It is finding the resource through meta data, but there is no Xaml metadata in the WinUI component, and I don't know how I would generate it.

Comment: `ms-appx:///` designates an absolute path.

Comment: @IInspectable I know it is an absolute path to the root of the application bundle, but I mean an absolute system path. If it still doesn't work with a path starting in C:/ or similar, then the issue is elsewhere. That would be useful for diagnosing the problem.

Comment: That's rather a comment then, not an answer.